# Issue understanding pin functions of a programmable current source from manual?

Tags: current-source

Here is the link to the manual: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3092fc.pdf

I am confused about the pin functions, in particular IN and SET (page 8). I gathered that OUT needs to be the current produced, but from the written definition I can't tell the difference between IN and SET.

- Is IN just the power going in? In which case, would I provide it 2V and 1mA as specified in electrical characteristics?
- And so, would SET be the digital input which switches the component on? So I'd get no OUT as long as SET is 0?

Sorry if they are stupid questions.

Answer (score 2):

The LT3092 is a floating two-terminal current source.  So you can put it between two nodes in a circuit, and as long as there is enough voltage across it (V(IN) = 1.2V to 40V above V(OUT) in the right direction) it will regulate the current through it to its setpoint.

[image]

The Rset pin connects as shown in the diagram.  The 10uA internal current source forces a current in the Rset resistor which develops a reference voltage for the internal error amplifier.  The amplifier will try to force the same voltage across Rout, thus regulating the current to 10uA*Rset/Rout.  So the two terminals of the current source are the "IN" terminal and the junction of Rset and Rout.  You get to choose the two resistors based on your application (read the datasheet section entitled "Selecting RSET and ROUT").

Answer (score 0):

You provide a voltage to IN.  This voltage must be at least 1.2V to 1.4V above the necessary voltage at the OUT pin.  You must calculate the necessary voltage at the OUT pin based on your current and SET and OUT resistors.

The SET and OUT resistors determine the current.  See the datasheet for how to calculate those resistors and wire up the pins.